# Using git with 2 laptops and multiple identities

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, public-key

I started a project on my office computer. Now I'm trying to move development to my home laptop. But my home laptop already has keys of own (for several other projects).

This particular project is on bitbucket. Others on this computer are on assembla and several other places.  So I thought about trying to create keys in addition to id_rsa (existing set) for my office key.

I did exactly that, but my keys are called `bitbucket` instead of `id_rsa`. So I created `config file` in `~/.ssh` and put this code in it with proper indentation. I'm using Tower for GIT and it gives me error:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now I am not sure if this was all I had to do. Did I miss some step? How do I go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the new public key to bitbucket? See the "Cause" section for this issue on the Bitbucket Knowledge Base [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=302811860).